# WpDatacharts (Highcharts render) - is it possible to pre-hide data sets on load?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've created a chart comparing rugby team rankings over time, at https://www.rugby4cast.com/code-test/. The chart has been generated using data from a table created using the WpDatatable plugin (visible below the chart).

I want to display this chart in multiple places, but only with two teams' lines showing at a time. E.g. on one page I want to display just the lines for Australia and England, for example, with the rest hidden. On another I want to display just Samoa and Fiji. Etc.

I know you can click on the legend to hide a dataset, but is it possible to assign this 'hidden' state in advance? Ideally I would choose which teams I want to be visible using the shortcode. E.g. [wpdatacharts id=11 team_1=England team_2=Wales] would show the England and Wales lines on load, and all the rest would be in the hidden state.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps you can add an additional column to this table with a status of the row - visible or not. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

Set the initial visibility of the series.

```
visible: boolean
```

Based on your requirement you can set it as true or false to display the series.

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.visible

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-visible/

Comment: Hi Ashu - thanks for your help! As this chart is generated from the WpDataTable table (below it), how can I change the 'visible' status on that page? I can see how I would do it if entering the javascript for the chart myself, but I'm not sure how to do it for this plugin-generated chart. Thanks!